# Fast boot with only 4gb USB drives

Tags: boot, live-usb, persistence

I am needing to install a persistent boot that has the swap partition, the persistent boot, and the casper-rw partition instead of the compressed file.

What I was thinking is breaking it down like this:
1024mb SWAP, 2gb Live Ubuntu 14.04 with persistent boot, 1gb casper-rw partition in ext4.

I have read on forums that making a partition of 1gb, naming it casper-rw, and deleting the casper-rw file will just load the casper-rw partition instead of the file.

The main reason I want to do it this way is the cost of USB drives. I do this all day remaking these drive from corruptions. Just replacing the casper-rw file doesn't really. I have hundreds of 4gb sticks, the 8gb sticks would cost money, and I'd still have the 4gb sticks.

now my questions:

1)Would a set-up like this work?

2)What file format does the 1024mb SWAP file need to be in.

3)What is the procedure for telling the grub, or file, to use the partition as a swap?

Additional information: This is the only HDD on the system, so it will always be SDA

Comment: You can get a 128GB USB Flash drive for $20. Are you sure you don't want to get something larger than 4GB? 2GB might not even be enough for a non-persistent LiveUSB.

Comment: I need 300 of these little buggers. They only boot some testing software, report results to a database and shut off.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that would work, though I think it's not enough space for a GUI unless you use something like Lubuntu, which might or might not work.

The swap would be an entire partition with no format; the partition type would simply be set to `swap` rather than, say, `ext4`.

You don't tell GRUB about the swap partition, since GRUB only cares about the earliest parts of booting the operating system. Instead, you tell Linux by editing `/etc/fstab` to say what partition to use (see your own system's `/etc/fstab` for an example; it'll have a line mentioning `swap`). Use `sudo blkid` after booting froto get the proper UUID for your USB drive's swap partition.